# What's the best thing to do in the 30 minutes before an exam?

Tags: exams, learning, independent-study

I have a highschool exam tomorrow morning and we've been given a short period before the exam officially begins to study. I'm just wondering what I should do in that time. Should I read and read and read over my notes, should I make flash cards and practice everything, should I rest? Any tips?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. It also can't be answered because it depends on the specific circumstances and, most importantly, it depends on you and what works for you. Maybe you should reread your notes, maybe you should meditate, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question for exams in general, the ideal thing to do before the last half hour before the exam differs from one person to another.

For some people, it would be best to relax in this time. For most others, it would be better to give a glance of the short notes they have to give them a confidence of what they know.

However, for the last 15 minutes before the exam, it is highly recommended that you do not go over your study material as it would be counterproductive. It would technically not be possible to read through your entire syllabus at this point, leaving some people feeling a state of incompleteness, even though it is only another revision. This feeling of being incomplete may heighten your stress levels causing you to underperform.